# setting text watcher to edit text in another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have two fragments, the first contains three edit texts and the second contains some text views that depends on the data from the edit texts in the first fragment, I tried to implement text watcher in the second fragment to watch the changes in the edit texts from the first fragment so that I can use it but it didn't work out.

my second fragment which contains text views that shows data depending on texts from edit texts in first fragment :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle notUsed) {
        super.onActivityCreated(notUsed);

        MainActivity1.text1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                co1 = Double.valueOf(charSequence.toString());
                if(charSequence.length() == 0)
                    empty1 = true;
                else
                    empty1 = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                co1 = Double.valueOf(editable.toString());
                if(editable.length() == 0)
                    empty1 = true;
                else
                    empty1 = false;
            }
        });

        MainActivity1.text2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                co2 = Double.valueOf(charSequence.toString());
                if(charSequence.length() == 0)
                    empty2 = true;
                else
                    empty2 = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                co2 = Double.valueOf(editable.toString());
                if(editable.length() == 0)
                    empty2 = true;
                else
                    empty2 = false;
            }
        });

        MainActivity1.text3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                co3 = Double.valueOf(charSequence.toString());
                if(charSequence.length() == 0)
                    empty3 = true;
                else
                    empty3 = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                co3 = Double.valueOf(editable.toString());
                if(editable.length() == 0)
                    empty3 = true;
                else
                    empty3 = false;
            }
        });
```

knowing that I had to make my edit texts from the first fragment `static` so that the second fragment could deal with it, I need to update text views in fragment two in real time when user change text in edit texts in fragment one,  how to make it work?

Comment: why not to use just callback instead of watcher?

Comment: I need to update text views in fragment two in real time when user change text in edit texts in fragment one

Comment: you can use callback for notifying changes in EditText in second fragment. In OnTextChange method call callback.

Comment: I'm sorry, that snippet from my code was from second fragment...I edited my question, I tried calling OnTextChanged from my second fragment but it doesn't work

Comment: Easiest way would be to use EventBus to post event (edittext text changed) from first fragment and consume the event in second fragment to update the textviews.